# Excel: how to calculate percentage within 24h when have dynamic data (over 24h)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-2016

I cant figure out how to calculate percentage within one day (24h) with a set of data that is dynamically changing, you have one day and different time as you can see on the SS. But thing is, I can calculate general difference between time using `=MOD (B3-B2,1)` and then just convert that into percentage (and I am getting just small % portion within one day). But problem persists when the time is after 23:59...

That "System" Column is actually two processes that are alternately working, so one is OFF other is ON and both got that date/time (working time).

How to calculate % one system within one day - so its working time in percentage per one day (so, for 10.01, 11.01..)

[image]

Something like this, and then lets say SUM of percentages withing one day for one system. There gives me over 100% for many examples (dates). 
[image]

[image]

I got a different data set (tried on other examples) and didnt work good:

```
 SUMIFS($B$2:$B$1020;$A$2:$A$1020;$F3;$C$2:$C$1020;"<>"&G$1)-SUMIFS($B$2:$B$1020;$A$2:$A$1020;$F3;$C$2:$C$1020;G$1)+(INDEX($C$2:$C$1020;MATCH($F3;$A$2:$A$1020))=G$1)
```

Is it maybe cuz I edited my data from PowerQuery and then inputed to the sheet? or anything else?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to get a percentage of. Are you saying that you want to know what the percentage of a day's time happens between each on and off?

Comment: Or do you perhaps want the total percentage of a day that it is on?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2  Yes, sorry, will Edit it! I need per one day per system...

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 but observe that date transition, from 10th to 11th , or 11th on 12th.. one system is being active longer than another...  that is actually most of a problem to "cut it" somehow within a day....because percentages has to be up to 100% and with this, I am getting over 100% what isnt good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bearing in mind that a day starts from t=0 and ends in t=1 where t is time in days, for two processes A and B we can consider four scenarios:

```
Start with process A, end with process B

|___A1---B1___A2---B2___|

B1-A1+B2-A2

∑B - ∑A

Start with process A, end with process A

|___A1---B1___A2---B2___A3---|

B1-A1+B2-A2+1-A3

∑B - ∑A +1

Start with process B, end with process A

|---B1___A1---B2___A2---|

B1-0+B2-A1+1-A2

∑B - ∑A +1

Start with process B, finish with process B

|---B1___A1---B2___A2---B3___|

B1-0+B2-A1+B3-A2

∑B - ∑A
```

Where A1 is the first on time for process A, A2 the second etc. and --- means process A is on and ___ means process A is off.

So we can just subtract the sum of the start times for process A from the sum of the start times for process B and add 1 if the last process in the day is process A.

Formula for a full day (like 11/1/19)

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$23,$A$2:$A$23,$F3,$C$2:$C$23,"<>"&G$1)-SUMIFS($B$2:$B$23,$A$2:$A$23,$F3,$C$2:$C$23,G$1)+(INDEX($C$2:$C$23,MATCH($F3,$A$2:$A$23))=G$1)
```

[image]

What about the first day, where there is nothing before half past one? Now it is wrong to assume that anything before process A is occupied by process B and vice versa, so have to subtract the first time if the first process is not process A and add another term to the calculation:

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$23,$A$2:$A$23,$F2,$C$2:$C$23,"<>"&G$1)-SUMIFS($B$2:$B$23,$A$2:$A$23,$F2,$C$2:$C$23,G$1)+(INDEX($C$2:$C$23,MATCH($F2,$A$2:$A$23))=G$1)-(INDEX($C$2:$C$23,MATCH($F2,$A$2:$A$23,0))<>G$1)*$B2
```

So the total time on the first day is not 24 hours but about 10.5 hours or 44% of a day.

Comment: thank you for this elaboration!  I didnt think of this... I tried in Pivots to solve it...still better than mine before.

Anyways, this formula from you is not working by me...dont know how why?!

Comment: Oh dear! None of it is working :-( Can you check that the dates and times are definitely actual dates and times not text plz? For example, if you change the format to General on the first date and time they should give 43475 0.56462963 if correctly entered.

Comment: Hmm actually no, I copied these columns from other sheets, maybe that is a reason..

Comment: It works! You were right. I did just =DATEVALUE to the date/time fields, and god exactly what I wanted!  
Many thanks for this help, simply amazing!

Comment: !!! Something is wrong again, tried on different data set but seems something is wrong...percentages are over 100%,500%.... check my last picture. 
I edited data in PowerQuery, with adequate data type...before I didnt use PowerQuery and seemed good.

Comment: It looks as if the percentages in your first column in your last picture are OK, so maybe something is wrong with copying the formula to the second column (STYRAX)? Formula in H3 should be =SUMIFS($B$2:$B$1020,$A$2:$A$1020,$F3,$C$2:$C$1020,"<>"&H$1)-SUMIFS($B$2:$B$1020,$A$2:$A$1020,$F3,$C$2:$C$1020,H$1)+(INDEX($C$2:$C$1020,MATCH($F3,$A$2:$A$1020))=H$1)

Comment: It's worth adding that they will be an issue if there are any gaps, like in your earlier set of data it goes straight from 14.0.2019 to 16.01.2019 and you don't know when scrubber ends (unless it is running all the way through 15.01.2019)

Comment: Well yeah, my data isnt always "consistent" due the system working, cant affect that nor change the "gaps" between. So you would say it might be a major issue?

Comment: Sorry for this spamming, but seems it works even with "gaps", got like difference of month or so, but still calculates last "activity" of the system... still, when I compare with my previous calculation, this makes more sense than mine !!!! 

Just one thing is a bit strange, I have to use DATEVALUE/TIMEVALUE to convert my data into proper values, even if they are already "date/time".

Comment: Strange about having to use DATEVALUE/TIMEVALUE, does sound as if they are somehow formatted as text. Yes unfortunately gaps would be an issue - you would have to do something like I did on the first day, to put in a correction, but you would have to have some way of identifying the gaps in the first place - either flagging them manually, or putting in a rule like 'if time difference > 18 hours treat it as a gap' - that's just a guess. Would make it more complicated and you still don't know where the last period before the gap ends..

Comment: I just went through many examples with gaps and without and it works exactly I wanted to. Those "gaps" are actually days when the System was OFF or was some kind of an error and due to that was OFF or stopped. It is fine to have those "gaps" in the chart for better understanding and bette overview of what is going on. 

I wanna say many thanks for you effort in this case. I am really happy about how you explained this. Simply amazing. 

cheers